# My second last value is garbage,the program is about calculating sum

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, visual-c++, dynamic

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int oldsize;

        string choice;
        cout << "Welcome to the Walmart Calculation Center!";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Number of Items" << endl;
        cin >> oldsize;
        int* items = new int[oldsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)
        {
            cout << "ENTER THE PRICE OF ITEM" << i + 1 << "!" << endl;
            cin >> items[i];
        }
           cout << "Do you want to add more items? (YES OR NO)" << endl;
           cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "YES")
        {
            int newbie;
            int newsize;


            int total = 0;
            while (choice == "YES")
            {
                newsize = oldsize + 1;
                int* Nitems = new int[newsize];

                for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)
                {
                    Nitems[i] = items[i];
                }
                cout << "Enter the Price of New ITEM!" << endl;
                cin >> newbie;
                Nitems[oldsize] = newbie;
                oldsize = newsize;
                cout << "Do you want to add more items? (YES OR NO)" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice=="NO")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
                    {
                        cout << Nitems[i] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

This program is about calculating sum of the bill at a store. and ask user that if he/she wants to enter any other item, until he/she says no. In the end it displays the total bill.

Comment: All variables in C++ need to be initialised before use. `int newsize = 0;` for example.

Comment: Use vectors for your requirement for initializing the arrays dynamically. There's no rule for initializing the array length at runtime, they must be static.

Comment: @RohanBari There is no VLA here, all arrays are dynamically allocated.

Comment: @RohanBari Brother since i am student,i have not learned vectors as of yet. Is there any other way of fixing this problem?Thankyou

Comment: Hint: for each new item you copy elements from the original array `items` (which never changes after initial read), but you change `oldsize`, which defines the length of the array.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen can you explain with more clarity?thankyou

Comment: *since i am student,i have not learned vectors as of yet* -- Many students learn `vector` before learning `new[]`, so being a student really is no excuse for not using vector.

Comment: You have array `items` with size `oldsize`. For the first iteration of `while` loop, you copy elements from `items` to `Nitems`, that's fine. But then, you change `oldsize` to `oldsize+1` and try to do the same - copy elements from `items` to `Nitems`. But now `oldsize` is not the size of `items` anymore, you go past the array and copy some rubbish.

Comment: You also have memory leaks, since I don't see where you `delete[]` the old memory.  Again, all this is taken care of by using `std::vector`.

Comment: @Newbie -- I pointed out you are leaking memory.  Is that not helpful?  Your instructor didn't teach that you need to call `delete[]` for every call to `new[]` you make, and myself (and others) need to take our time as contributors to take the place of your teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change `items` array, but you change `oldsize` variable which represents it's size. When you the try to copy items from `items` to `Nitems`, you go out of bounds of `items` array (because `oldsize` is bigger that actual size of array).

The simplest fix would be to repoint `items` to `Nitems` at the same moment when you change the size.

```
while (choice == "YES")
{
    newsize = oldsize + 1;
    int* Nitems = new int[newsize];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)
    {
        Nitems[i] = items[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter the Price of New ITEM!" << endl;
    cin >> newbie;
    Nitems[oldsize] = newbie;

    oldsize = newsize;
    items = Nitems; //here

    cout << "Do you want to add more items? (YES OR NO)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice=="NO")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
        {
            cout << Nitems[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

See the line marked with comment? It makes `items` pointer point to the same array as `Nitems`. There is no copying involved, if you change `items[1]`, `Nitems[1]` would see the same change. But having two pointers to the same array let's you keep the current array when you create new array in the next iteration.

---

There is of course problem with memory leaks, but don't worry too much about that until you learn how to manage memory properly. Badly placed `delete` is much worse that memory leak (especially in such small programs).

---

And of course, your code would be much simpler if you used `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> items;
while (choice == "YES")
{
    cout << "Enter the Price of New ITEM!" << endl;
    cin >> newbie;
    items.push_back(newbie);

    cout << "Do you want to add more items? (YES OR NO)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice=="NO")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << items[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT BROTHER! I get it,can you explain me about these memory leaks? I don't know what is this? would be really helpful.

Comment: Call to `new` operator reserves some memory and it's programmers' responsibility to free this memory. Therefore each call to `new` should have a corresponding `delete` and each call to `new[]` should have a `delete[]`. But doing it properly is a difficult thing, therefore usage of `new` should be minimized. With smart pointers and containers you almost never need it (I don't think I ever used raw `new` in my 3 years of professional work). In your code you'd have to use `delete[] items;` before reassigning `items` to point to new array.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment due to low reputation. But I feel you are still unclear about dynamic allocation concepts. You will need to `delete` if you create something using `new` to avoid memory leaks. This program can be much simpler like below. I still use `new` deliberately to show the `delete` scenario. Apart from that you also need to clear up some basics as given in comments. All the best!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int oldsize, newbie;
        int total=0;
        string choice;
        cout << "Welcome to the Walmart Calculation Center!";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the Number of Items" << endl;
        cin >> oldsize;
        int* items = new int[oldsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)
        {
            cout << "ENTER THE PRICE OF ITEM" << i + 1 << "!" << endl;
            cin >> items[i];
            total+=items[i];
        }
        do {
            cout << "Do you want to add more items? (YES OR NO)" << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            //if user inputs NO, break out of do while.
            if(choice == "NO") break;

            //continue here if YES
            cout << "Enter the Price of New ITEM!" << endl;
            cin >> newbie;
            total+=newbie;

        }while(choice=="YES");

        cout << "Total: " << total << endl;

    delete[] items;

    }
```